# Named Entity Recognition for Italian

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I'd like to use an NLP tool to extract names and numbers from an **Italian** text.

Sadly, neither [The Standford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Download) nor [Apache OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) provide a model for Italian.

Were can I find one, or find the training data to make one? (at least 15,000 sentences)

Comment: You could try [l'enciclopedia libera](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale).

Answer (score 4):

[Italian Content Annotation Bank](http://ontotext.fbk.eu/icab.html) has some NER-annotated data. Not sure about the size, though. As for numbers, I think a simple rule-based approach could do the trick.